# How I do mysql update of a selected query in same table?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE suggest 
SET 
`    post_id`="5286" 
where 
  `post_id`  IN 

( SELECT `post_id` FROM `suggest` WHERE `word` LIKE "%word%" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a subquery here.

```
UPDATE suggest 
SET `post_id`="5286" 
WHERE `word` LIKE "%word%"
```

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Here is an  post regarding this .

You can achieve this using this query .

```
update suggest as a inner join (select post_id from suggest where word like '%word%') as b on a.post_id = b.post_id set a.post_id="5286";
```